# DST and PHP Date and Timestamps

Tags: php, timestamp, dst

I have searched the list for an prior answer, but can't find one. We are using PHP 4.4.8 and **need a PHP 4 answer**. We have an array of timestamps [$d] representing:

> 1478404800  2016-11-06 00:00:00
>
> 1478494800  2016-11-07 00:00:00

2016-11-06 is the transition day for DST to Std time.

We want to store a timestamp that represents 1:00pm on each day, so we  did

```
$e2 = $d+46800
```

46800 is 13 hours worth of seconds.

```
date("D d M Y g a I",$e2)
```

returns:

> Sun 06 Nov 2016 12 pm 0
>
> Mon 07 Nov 2016 1 pm 0

The trailing 0 is the DST indicator. Nov 6 seems to be indicating the DST to STD "fallback" 1 hour. We don't want DST reflected.

So the questions are:

1. How do we get a Nov 6th answer that doesn't reflect DST to STD.
2. If this is DST, why for one day? Nov 7th didn't get any "fallback"

Users are not in different time zones, so we needn't worry about time zones.

Comment: "We needn't worry about time zones" doesn't make sense.  DST is *only* applicable within a specific time zone.  The entire world does not have DST, and those that have it do not all do it over the same dates or at the same time of day.  So either a time zone is applicable to your question, or your question doesn't involve DST.  You can't have it both ways.

Comment: All of our users are in one time zone. We don't need a solution that works across multiple time zones with different DST or not.

Comment: It would help to know *which* time zone you are using.

Comment: We are in America/Los_Angeles timezone.

Comment: which version are you using? really?

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear what you're asking for exactly, but if your only concern is the `date()` return value - tell PHP to create the correct UNIX timestamp:

```
mktime(13, 0, 0, 11, 6, 2016);
```

Though, I'd be more concerned that you're still running PHP 4 on this date.